# Generic Factory method to create generic types ins and outs

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following implementation which generates a compiler error

> "Cannot implicitly convert type '`ParentMenuItemFilter`' to
>   '`IMenuItemFilter<MenuItem>`'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

```
public class MenuItem
{
    // implementation removed for clarity
}

public class ParentMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    // implementation removed for clarity
}

public interface IMenuItemFilter<TMenuItemType>
        where TMenuItemType : MenuItem
{
    TMenuItemType ApplySecurity(TMenuItemType menuItem);
}


public class ParentMenuItemFilter : IMenuItemFilter<ParentMenuItem>
{
    public ParentMenuItem ApplySecurity(ParentMenuItem menuItem)
    {
        // implementation removed for clarity
    }
}

public class MenuItemFilterFactory
{
    public IMenuItemFilter<MenuItem> Create<TMenuItemType>(TMenuItemType menuItem)
            where TMenuItemType : MenuItem
    {
        if (typeof(TMenuItemType) == typeof(ParentMenuItem))
        {
            // here is the errored line!...
            return new ParentMenuItemFilter(this);
        }
        else if (/* create some other types*/)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So my two best friends, covariance and contravariance come in to play.  I want to achieve the above if it is possible, by the generic factory method, which will return the appropriate instance of the `IMenuItemFilter`, which is going to act upon the `menuItem` parameter to the `Create` method.

I want to pass the `MenuItem` instance to the factory method for this to be resolved.

I have tried having an in and out `in TMenuItemTypeIn, out TMenuItemTypeOut` in the interface and other definitions - to no avail.  I was 50/50 on posting this to CodeReview on Stack Exchange but thought this is equally a coding problem as well as a code design issue. I've spent best part of today trying to get this working but have had a lot of disruptions.

Comment: I suppose all you need is `public interface IMenuItemFilter<out TMenuItemType>`. However it´s quite un-generic if your checking against the actual type, isn´t it? I doubt you need generics for your scenario, or at least not for your factory.

Comment: I cant just have the out as IMenuItemFilter specifies the same TMenuItemType as both in and out parameter? The compiler barfs at this one!

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't returning `IMenuItemFilter<TMenuItemType>` from your factory method?

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't a overly simplistic example, you really should have one method per type, e.g. `CreateParentMenuItemFilter` or something like that. Your generic approach seems to only complicate things without any benefit.

Comment: Indeed, the cracks are appearing.  I was looking for an elegant approach to this - just rethinking the code strategy on the overall problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose all you need is `public interface IMenuItemFilter<out TMenuItemType>`. However having a generic method that does different things based on the generic type-param is a bit strange and not the intention of generics - that´s why they are called *generics*: they do the same for different classes.

So I suggest go un-generic in your factory:

```
public class MenuItemFilterFactory
{
    public IMenuItemFilter Create(MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        if (menuItem.GetType() == typeof(ParentMenuItem))
        {
            return new ParentMenuItemFilter(this);
        }
        else if (/* create some other types*/)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This however assumes you have a non-generic version of your interface as well from which the generic one derives:

```
public interface IMenuItemFilter
{
}
public interface IMenuItemFilter<TMenuItemType> : IMenuItemFilter
        where TMenuItemType : MenuItem
{
    TMenuItemType ApplySecurity(TMenuItemType menuItem);
}
```

Comment: But if I return `IMenuItemFilter` from the factory I cannot access the `ApplySecurity` method which is on `IMenuItemFilter<TMenuItemType>`